# SSH: connect from one remote server to another

Tags: ssh

I have a 2 distant server called LAMPserver and DBserver (both on Ubuntu 14.04).
I can connect to both server via ssh from my local machine and can connext from DBserver to LAMPserver via SSH but not from LAMPserver to DBserver.

I ran the basic tests:
- pointing to the right server (I can access LAMPserver from my local machine via SSH)
- firewall: none on DBserver
`iptables -L` returns on LAMPserver:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:ftp-data:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/RST limit: avg 1/sec burst 5

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:ftp-data:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

- port 22 open on bother LAMPserver and DBserver (check using: http://mxtoolbox.com)
- both server are listening on port 22 (check via ssh config nano `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)
- ssh server are started on both server

My firewall on LAMPserver:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Remove all rules
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X

# Forbid all traffic
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow established connection
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow FTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SMTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT

# Allow POP3
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT

# Allow POPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

# Allow IMAP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT

# Allow IMAPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP (ping)
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# NTP (horloge du serveur)
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Prevent Flood or Ddos
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT

# Limit port scan
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
```

LAMPserver is set up with SSL. 
Any ideas will be really welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your OUTPUT chain it looks like you made a small mistake:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh
```

When connecting to a remote SSH server the source port should be random (range: 1024-65535) and the destination port is 22.

Try changing your "# Allow SSH" block to the following:

```
# Allow SSH
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: @CSQGB Hi, please ask a new question if you have one following the answer, as you maybe have other issue in your configuration that the OP didnt had.